# Show Rows based on values in multiple columns. JQuery

Tags: jquery

In JQuery hiding a table row based on a predefined columns td value is easy using the following code.

```
function filterRows(word){
$('.application>tbody>tr')
.show()
.find('td:nth-child(2)').not(':contains("'+word+'")')
.parent()
.hide()
}
```

However how would I go about showing rows that match td values in more than one column.

Something like the following (which does not work)

```
function filterRows(word){
$('.application>tbody>tr')
.show()
.find('td:nth-child(2)').not(':contains("'+word+'")')
.find('td:nth-child(3)').not(':contains(30)')
.parent()
.hide()
}
```

Basically I want to be able to show only rows where my word is passed in "word" is in the second column td and the third column contains "30".

Thanks for any heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to hop back in the chain, like this:

```
function filterRows(word){
  $('.application>tbody>tr').show()
    .find('td:nth-child(2)').not(':contains("'+word+'")').parent().hide()
    .end().end().end() //back 3 spots for parent, not and find
    .find('td:nth-child(3)').not(':contains(30)').parent().hide();
}
```

Though, in this case chaining is a bit verbose, just keep a reference in a variable, like this:

```
function filterRows(word){
  var rows = $('.application>tbody>tr').show();
  rows.find('td:nth-child(2):not(:contains("'+word+'"))').parent().hide();
  rows.find('td:nth-child(3):not(:contains(30))').parent().hide();
}
```

Or a bit more complex selector:

```
function filterRows(word){
  $('.application>tbody>tr').show()
    .find('td:nth-child(2):not(:contains("'+word+'")), td:nth-child(3):not(:contains(30))').parent().hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution to my issue.I used the selector in the 3rd code block. Next stop is getting a book on JQuery and learning it in more depth to understand where selectors can be nested etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting `.parent()` after the first find.

```
.find('td:nth-child(2)').not(':contains("'+word+'")').parent()
```

Comment: This would make the second find only look in the first find's results.

Comment: I think he is wanting to select rows which satisfies both conditions (conjunction), so hoping back in the previos set is not useful.
Some experiments herE: http://jsfiddle.net/N25pM/

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterrows(word) {
  var row = $(".application>tbody>tr");
  row.each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    var secondColumn = $('td:nth-child(2):not(contains("'+word+'"))', $this)
    var thirdColumn= $('td:nth-child(2):not(:contains("30")', $this)
    if (secondColumn.length && thridcolumn.length) {  //if you find both a second and third column that matches
      $this.hide();
    } else { //if the second and third column dont match
      $this.show();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This would fire up the selector engine `2n+1` times, `n` being the number of rows...plus create about `2n` more jQuery objects...the performance would be very, very bad especially with larger tables.  Also it's not correct, your `if` check would *always* be `true` since you're checking `if(jQueryObject && jQueryObject)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more efficient way to do it:

```
function filterRows(word){
    $('.application>tbody>tr').show()
        .filter(function() {
            return this.cells[ 1 ].innerHTML.indexOf( word ) < 0 ||
                   this.cells[ 2 ].innerHTML.indexOf( "30" ) < 0;
        }).hide()
}
```

If there are nested tags, a slightly different approach should be taken in the filter. In that case, you would replace `this.cells[ 1 ].innerHTML` with:

```
(this.cells[ 1 ].innerText || this.cells[ 1 ].textContent)
```

*(Same for `cells[ 2 ]` of course.)*

---

**EDIT:** I had `&&` instead of `||`. Sounds like the requirement is to `.show()` if both matches are found. Fixed. Now it will hide if either match is not found.